# When joining tables, date column is NULL on some etries

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to migrate some custom CMS DB to Wordpress, and so far it's been a living hell.
I am using WP All import plugin, so I need a neat single .csv export that contains data from multiple tables from this custom cms database.

So, these are the columns from two tables that I want to join:

```
`eo_items`
| cat_id | identificator      | create_date |
---------------------------------------------
|   1    | Title of the post  | 1283786285  |

`eo_items_trans`
| item_id | lid | name              | s_desc  | l_desc  |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    1    |  33 | Title of the post | excerpt | content |
```

Desired result should be:

```
| item_id | lid | name              | s_desc  | l_desc  | cat_id | create_date |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1    |  33 | Title of the post | excerpt | content |    1   | Some date   |
```

Here is the script I am using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
eo_items_trans.item_id, 
eo_items_trans.lid, 
eo_items.cat_id, 
DATE_FORMAT(    eo_items.create_date,  '%d.%m.%Y' ) create_date, 
eo_items_trans.s_desc, 
eo_items_trans.l_desc, 
eo_items_trans.name
FROM eo_items_trans
LEFT JOIN eo_items ON ( eo_items_trans.name = eo_items.identificator )
```

Trouble with this code is that in resulting table some date columns are NULL, and I don't know if the result is what I need because the table has around 2000 rows and I don't know how to cross check if category IDs are correctly populated.

This is the first time I am doing something like this with MySQL so I am really not sure if the procedure is right for what I am trying to achieve.

If you need any clarifications please ask.

**EDIT:**

`eo_items` table has some 300 rows more than `eo_items_trans` so there are some records there that don't have corresponding records in `eo_items_trans`. I am guessing this should be reflected in the query as well?

Comment: Only the `create_date` yields null and no other columns?

Comment: some other columns as well, I edited the question, basically `eo_items` has more rows that `eo_items_trans`

Comment: Then you need an INNER JOIN, not LEFT JOIN. I assume you don't know what the difference is, so you should investigate what each does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You NULL results for date seem to come or from eo_items_trans records that have no corresponding entry in the eo_items table or from eo_items records where create_date is null.

You can easily crosscheck check by doing the following

Is there records in eo_items_trans that have no corresponding entries in eo_items:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT eo_items_trans.name FROM eo_items_trans
 where NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * FROM  eo_items 
                   where eo_items.identificator = eo_items_trans.name
                  )
```

If this yields one ore more rows, that will be the eo_items_trans.name records with no correspondent in eo_items. If this is you problem, the do a JOIN, not a LEFT join in your main query

As for empty dates in eo_items you might want to check like this

```
 SELECT * from eo_items WHERE create_date IS NULL
```

If you find records here, this is where yout NULL values in the main query come from

Comment: So, `SELECT * from eo_items WHERE create_date IS NULL` is not returning anything,  `SELECT DISTINCT eo_items_trans.name where NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  eo_items where eo_items.identificator = eo_items_trans.name)` gives syntax error. I tried with only `JOIN` and I still get the nulls. `eo_items` has more rows than `eo_items_trans` so yeah, i gueass there are some records that are not corresponding. How to go about it?

Comment: @Bojana_Šekeljić , Maybe the dat string in eo_items.create_date is somehow indigestible? what if you run the query without the data conversion ? Do you still get NULL ?

Comment: @Bojana_Šekeljić , synthax error in not exists query, can you dump the full error here ?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM eo_items ' at line 2

Comment: did it wothout data conversion, some are still NULL, but a lot less than before. Before it was the case with around 50% of entries, now around 10%

Comment: @Bojana_Šekeljić, synthax error, missed the from part, edited my answer, try again ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52318/discussion-between-freud-chicken-and-bojana-sekeljic)

Comment: Breaktrough - I did `INNER JOIN` instead of `JOIN LEFT`, as recomended by @N.B and without formatting for the date, and there are no NULLS, so it s the formatting? any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using a `LEFT JOIN`, `NULL`s will be returned for any rows of `eo_items_trans` that do not have entries in `oe_items`. This could mean the `eo_items.identificator` is empty, or doesn't exactly match the name (case sensitivity will apply).

You'll have to investigate and clean up the data for rows in `eo_items_trans` missing the expected row in `eo_items`.